# React.js: array.map/forEach wont print on screen but console.log works

Tags: reactjs, arrays, jsx

I have a function that needs to find nearest parent id, the result is in an object so I convert it to array then when I loop through the array and need to display it, it doesnt work. but when I check using console.log it is working fine. Any advice?

```
function findParentsProject(brands, id, parent = null) {
  for (let brand of brands) {
    const result =
      brand.id === id
        ? parent
        : brand.projects && findParentsProject(brand.projects, id, brand);
    if (result) {
      var list = Object.values(result.projects);
      return list.forEach((project, index) => {
        //console.log(project.name)
        <p>{project.name}</p>;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

this is the result if comment out the console.log
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy6jS.png)

here is the data(brands):

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "project 1",
      "typeOfWork": "Brand Identity",
      "brandDetails": "Strategy and brand id entity for the ambitious online art retailer",
      "Awards": "MARKies Awards 2021",
      "AwardDetails": "Most Creative Audio (Bronze)",
      "Content": "While this competition is healthy, it often means that competitors tend to produce similiar posts, thus drowning in the ocean of posts that in social media. How do make Allianz unique so it stands out more among the crowd, without so much resorting to pay-to-win?"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "project 2",
      "typeOfWork": "Editorial & Prints",
      "brandDetails": "Strategy and brand id entity for the ambitious online art retailer",
      "Awards": "MARKies Awards 2021",
      "AwardDetails": "Most Creative Audio (Bronze)",
      "Content": "While this competition is healthy, it often means that competitors tend to produce similiar posts, thus drowning in the ocean of posts that in social media. How do make Allianz unique so it stands out more among the crowd, without so much resorting to pay-to-win?"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "project 3",
      "typeOfWork": "Digital Design",
      "brandDetails": "Strategy and brand id entity for the ambitious online art retailer",
      "Awards": "MARKies Awards 2021",
      "AwardDetails": "Most Creative Audio (Bronze)",
      "Content": "While this competition is healthy, it often means that competitors tend to produce similiar posts, thus drowning in the ocean of posts that in social media. How do make Allianz unique so it stands out more among the crowd, without so much resorting to pay-to-win?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You `map` instead of `forEach` and `return` the statement since you are using `{}`. If it's just JSX you can directly use `items.maps(item => JSX)`

Comment: i do as u say, but still nothing displayed `list.map((project,index) => {
    return (
    //console.log(project.name)
    <p>{project.name}</p>
    )

})`

Comment: Check this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-swirles-5wgou9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) You can use that for your requirement.

Comment: hi, thank u for ur reply. I have go through ur codes and try it on my own yet still nothing displayed on the screen T.T anyway can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-clarke-hbtkb2?file=/src/App.js) data is updated it's actually nested array

Comment: It seems that Sandbox is not updated with your code. Can you check again?

Comment: oh my god im so sorry, ok should be updated now. thank you